# Event Name: APPCRASH Application Name: DtsDebugHost.exe

Tags: ssis, sql-server-2008-r2, db2, netezza

SSIS Debug Host has stopped working (here source is DB2 and destination is Netezza) with problem details:-

> Problem signature:   Problem Event Name:  APPCRASH   Application
>   Name: DtsDebugHost.exe   Application Version: 2009.100.1600.1
>   Application Timestamp:    4bb679ab   Fault Module Name:   DTSPipeline.dll
>   Fault Module Version: 2009.100.4042.0   Fault Module
>   Timestamp:    5514e504   Exception Code:  40000015   Exception
>   Offset:   00057653

And Error in SQLDUMPER file is

> > ACTION, SQLDUMPER_UNKNOWN_APP.EXE, AdjustTokenPrivileges () completed with status (00000514) ACTION, SQLDUMPER_UNKNOWN_APP.EXE,
> >     Input parameters: 4 supplied  ACTION, SQLDUMPER_UNKNOWN_APP.EXE,
> >       Parameter 1: 10148 ACTION, SQLDUMPER_UNKNOWN_APP.EXE,   Parameter 2: 0
> >     ACTION, SQLDUMPER_UNKNOWN_APP.EXE,    Parameter 3: 0:0 ACTION,
> >     SQLDUMPER_UNKNOWN_APP.EXE,    Parameter 4: 0000000000420B58  ACTION,
> >     SQLDUMPER_UNKNOWN_APP.EXE, Parsed parameters: ACTION,
> >     SQLDUMPER_UNKNOWN_APP.EXE,     ProcessID = 10148 ACTION,
> >     SQLDUMPER_UNKNOWN_APP.EXE,     ThreadId = 0  ACTION,
> >     SQLDUMPER_UNKNOWN_APP.EXE,     Flags = 0x0  ACTION,
> >     SQLDUMPER_UNKNOWN_APP.EXE,     MiniDumpFlags = 0x0  ACTION,
> >     SQLDUMPER_UNKNOWN_APP.EXE,     SqlInfoPtr = 0x0000000000420B58 ACTION,
> >     SQLDUMPER_UNKNOWN_APP.EXE,     DumpDir =  ACTION,
> >     SQLDUMPER_UNKNOWN_APP.EXE,     ExceptionRecordPtr = 0x0000000000000000
> >     ACTION, SQLDUMPER_UNKNOWN_APP.EXE,     ContextPtr = 0x0000000000000000
> >     ACTION, SQLDUMPER_UNKNOWN_APP.EXE,     ExtraFile =   ACTION,
> >     SQLDUMPER_UNKNOWN_APP.EXE,     InstanceName =  ACTION,
> >     SQLDUMPER_UNKNOWN_APP.EXE,     ServiceName =   ACTION,
> >     SQLDUMPER_UNKNOWN_APP.EXE, Callback type 11 not used  ACTION,
> >     SQLDUMPER_UNKNOWN_APP.EXE, Callback type 15 not used ACTION,
> >     SQLDUMPER_UNKNOWN_APP.EXE, Callback type 7 not used

When I execute this package from SQL Server Agent it throws me an error

> The step did not generate any output.  The return value was unknown.  The process exit code was 255.  The step failed.

FYI:- Packages are used to extract data from a source and it also has a execute SQL Task which calls a stored procedure. My other packages are working fine. To be precise on what I am doing is : Extract data and call stored procedure using execute sql task to update some rows. Do you think that something in this package might be going wrong? If not then what might be the reason

Any help would be appreciated !

Comment: Have you installed the latest service pack and/or CU? I would give that a try.

Comment: This doesn't sound like an issue with your package, sounds like you need to repair or reinstall your SQL Server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out the problem:
Run64BitRunTime was not consistent i.e. for some of the child packages it was True and for some it was false. Once I made Run64BitRunTime as true for all the packages, my issue was resolved.

Thanks for all the comments.[image]